# pd.cut failing on int64 intervalindex build from_arrays

Tags: python, pandas, binning

Pandas version: 0.20.1

I have some intervals

```
>print(periods)
IntervalIndex([(1459486800000000000, 1459490400000000000], (1459503000000000000, 1459506600000000000], (1459521000000000000, 1459524600000000000], (1459540800000000000, 1459544400000000000], (1459573200000000000, 1459576800000000000] ... (1475164800000000000, 1475168400000000000], (1475215860000000000, 1475219460000000000], (1475219460000000000, 1475223060000000000], (1475229660000000000, 1475233260000000000], (1475240400000000000, 1475244000000000000]]
              closed='right',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

I also have a `df` with a Start

```
print(df.head(3)['Start'].astype(np.int64))

1    1463725423954004000
2    1463725440994005000
5    1463732892934001000
```

I would like to use `pd.cut` on these periods. I have tried

```
 df['val'] = pd.cut(df['Start'].astype(np.int64), bins=periods)

But it get the following
    //python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/interval.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method)
    705                 return self._engine.get_loc_interval(left, right)
    706             else:
--> 707                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
    708 
    709     def get_value(self, series, key):

pandas/_libs/intervaltree.pxi in pandas._libs.interval.IntervalTree.get_loc (pandas/_libs/interval.c:9756)()
```

KeyError: 1463725423954004000

I can't figure out why I get this, after reading documentation

Comment: Please post a reproducible example; see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3339965)

Comment: Also try upgrading to the latest version of pandas; 0.20.1 is quite old, and `IntervalIndex` is quite new (first released in 0.20.0), so many bug fixes and improvements have been made since.

Comment: why is this not reproducible?

Comment: The exact content of `periods` is unknown; note the "..." in the string representation.  None of the intervals shown contain the value for which you're getting the `KeyError`.  All of the data you provide needs to be copy/pasteable in their entirety.

Comment: ok will do, please do not downote

Comment: we can close it if you know it is a version bug

Comment: No worries!  I'm not sure if it's a known bug that's been fixed, or an unknown bug that hasn't been reported yet.